# Неожиданное поведение jQuery AJAX в Windows XP

Tags: jquery, windows, firefox

Здравствуйте! 
Столкнулся с такой интересной проблемой, есть некая веб-форма, данные которой передаются в фоне скрипту на php посредством jQuery (AJAX).
А проблема следующая, есть три системы - Ubuntu, Windows 7, Windows XP, на всех стоят одинаковые версии браузеров (Chrome, Firefox). 
Если в первых двух всё работает без проблем, то в XP не срабатывает скрипт, либо возвращает ошибку Undefined Index для переданных значений. 
В чём может быть причина? Что необходимо дописать в скрипте, чтобы всё работало одинаково независимо от версии ОС?

Пример скрипта:

```
var content = $(this).serialize();
var fdata = new FormData();
fdata.append ('userfile', $('#userfile')[0].files[0])
fdata.append ('text', content);
$.ajax({
    type: method,
    url: action,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: fdata,
    success: function(result){
    }
```

Comment: Судя по всему, jQuery отрабатывает правильно, а вот **ответ сервера** разнится. Если PHP выполняется на трех машинах, то я бы действительно в первую очередь стал смотреть разницу в окружении. Тем не менее, клиентский код (яваскрипт) должен быть готов к подобным ситуациям.

Comment: Так вот я не могу понять в чём проблема, если одинаковые версии браузеров, то и JS по идее должен там одинаково работать и он корректно работает и в Linux и в Windows 7

Comment: В общем, нашёл проблему, в XP передаётся некорректный заголовок contentType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в некорректно передаваемом скриптом заголовке contentType, дело в том, что в скрипте неправильно расположены строки, получается что contentType передаётся раньше чем данные, соответственно не корректно передаются значения boundary. Корректный скрипт

```js
var content = $(this).serialize();
var fdata = new FormData();
fdata.append('userfile', $('#userfile')[0].files[0])
fdata.append('text', content);
$.ajax({
  type: method,
  url: action,
  data: fdata,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  success: function(result) {}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну судя по всему, на сервере вы пытаетесь достать из массива значение по ключу, которого в этом массиве нет. Собственно поэтому вы получаете: Undefined index.

Возможно на первых двух осях этой ошибки нет из за различных настроек PHP error reporting.

Я бы вам посоветовал научиться использовать дебаггер (он очень полезен при разработке).

Ну и еще бы я вам посоветовал более точно и без ошибок описывать ваши вопросы.

Comment: Причём тут error reporting, если это на сервере конфигурируется, ему по большому счёту без разницы какая ось/браузер у клиента.

Comment: Я вот именно по тому и добавил последний абзац, потому что из вопроса не понятно, какой скрипт возвращает ошибку и что за ошибка "Undefined Index". В ответе написал вам свое предположение.

Answer (score 0):

А вы уверены, что в других ОС скрипт работает, или так думаете, только потому что там ошибок нет. Проблема скорее всего в скрипте, а не в том, что разные ОС.
Выложите весь код и попробуйте протестировать работу во всех ОС ( **именно протестировать: проверить, отправляется ли запрос и приходит ли ответ** )

Comment: Конечно уверен. :)
Через консоль firebug или встроенную консоль в хроме, кроме того запись в базу проиходит как надо